# Vowpal Wabbit negative weights significance

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit

I'm doing a feature study and I was wondering what the negative feature weights in the audit output signify. I'm currently using the contextual bandits function with the following parameters:

```py
from vw.cb_explore_adf import CB_EXP_ADF

cb = CB_EXP_ADF('--cb_adf -q AA --audit --epsilon=0 --lambda=10', quite=True, enable_logging=True)
```

Here's an example of the audit output:

```
Incoming^category1=xqc115:61140:1:-0.0217842@53.4877    
ASpace^category2=Mali*ASpace^category1=Mali:143860:1:-0.0182445@70.8355 
ASpace^category3=Mali:213594:1:-0.0181837@70.7679
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative feature weights should not signify something special. Depending on the provided arguments and input data, vowpal wabbit will try to optimize the underlying problem (cb_adf reduces to a cost-sensitive one-against-all problem which reduces to a GD optimization problem)